# jQuery : Open next DIV based on Current div element

Tags: jquery, onclick

I've HTML structure like below.

```
<dl id="steps">
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
<div>
<h2>Some Title</h2>
<div class="options">
<div class="some-inputs"></div>
<div class="next"><input type="button class="btn" /></div>
</div>
<div class="options">
<div class="some-inputs"></div>
<div class="next"><input type="button class="btn" /></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</dl>
```

I want like, When document is ready above structure is hidden. Than after on click on element(Which is available in document) above structure will show up, But only first div, Which has class `options`.

**Note :  Div with class `some-options` contains different form inputs like text,radio,checkbox etc.**

So How Can I perform click on button class `btn` to activate parent div with class `options` and after click on next button on current activated div next div with class `options` will enable. It will continue so On.. Untill options div are there.

What I've tired.

```
$("#procced").click(function(){ 
    $("#steps").show();

    var i = 0;

});
```

Beginner with jQuery need some guide to make this possible.

`#procced is other element somewhere is DOM. I want to perform like when #procced is clicked question's HTML will show up. THat i did some how. Next is not whole structure will show but only first div with .options and its next button (obviously). Than click on .btn next .options will show up. previous will remain show`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( ".options" ).hide().first().show();
  
  $(".next").click(function(){ $(this).parents('.options').next().show();});
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl id="steps">
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
<div>
<h2>Some Title</h2>
<div class="options">options1
<div class="some-inputs"></div>
<div class="next"><input type="button" class="btn" /></div>
</div>
<div class="options">options1
<div class="some-inputs"></div>
<div class="next"><input type="button" class="btn" /></div>

</div>
<div class="options">options1
<div class="some-inputs"></div>
<div class="next"><input type="button" class="btn" /></div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</dl>
```

Hello You can do this

for fist time show

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#procced").click(function(){ 
  $( ".options" ).first().show();});});
```

and click of button for active parent option div you can do like this

`$(".btn").click(function(){ 
       $(this).parents('.options').first().addClass("active")
});`

and for next show you can do some thing like this

```
$(".next").click(function(){ 
   $(this).parents('.options').next().show();
```

please put "next" and "btn" click event in document.ready bracket

Comment: Please read updated question. I've only added `display:none` for #steps. I tried what you gave but it will show up all options div. I want to show up only first .options  than click on first options it will show next div with .options

Comment: for show next option you can make function like this 
$(".next").click(function(){ 
   $(this).parents('.options').next().show();});

Comment: and if possible please make jsfiddle and share it

Comment: I dont know how to share with jsfiddle. Can you create one and share with me so that I can update into it.

Comment: this my fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/rajdip250895/xpvt214o/971403/ and i have update answer please check code snippet

Comment: One for thing If you can help me out. Like I also want to check some condition when click perfomed on next button. As I said there are some input fields under div .some-inputs I want to check if .some-inputs has unchecked inputs than it won't show up next .options How to do this ?

Comment: I did try to upvote your answer but due to low reputations I cant Can you help me for above query ?

Comment: if possible please edit my fiddle and add condition so i can get batter idea of it

Answer (score 0):

You can do somethig like this:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      //Assuming you need to perform on "procced" id click
        $("#procced").click(function(){ 
          $( ".options" ).each(function() {
           if(!$( this ).is(':visible')) {
             $( this ).show()
             break; //break the loop
           }
         });
     });
});
```

Comment: No `#procced` is some other element, I need to show options when click performed on next button that has class `btn`. All div and next button has same class.

Comment: I assume you need to perform on "Procced" id

Comment: No #procced is other element somewhere is DOM. I want to perform like when #procced is clicked question's HTML will show up. THat i did some how.

Next is not whole structure will show but only first div with .options and its next button (obviously). Than click on .btn next .options will show up. previous will remain show.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#procced").click(function(){    
     if($('#steps').is(":visible") == true)
        {
            $('#steps options').each(function(element){
               if($(element).is(":visible") == false)
               {
                  $(element).show();
                  break;
               }
           })
        }
});
```